# Revert to using local account for SQL Server services

Tags: sql-server, service-accounts, configuration-manager

We have changed the login/startup account of our SQL Server service, to use a domain service account. However, we are experiencing issues with this account, and need to revert back to using the local `NT Service\MSSQL$[namedinstance]` account for now.

Is there a way of doing this? When prompted for the password in SQL Server Configuration Manager, what does one enter? We never set a password for this previously, but it appears to require one.

> The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified. [0x80070421]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to revert to a managed service account. If so, your not going to have access to the password. I found this article which may help: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5334/using-managed-service-accounts-with-sql-server/ It uses PowerShell to set the service account for a SQL server instance.

Comment: Thank you. In the end we had to resort to using the built-in "Local System" account (which requires no password) to get the instances working again, until we can get some gMSA's implemented.